# Mule Batch Negative seek offset & IllegalAccessError: sun/nio/cs/UTF_8

Tags: mule

I am  getting following error message while starting/running the application.

```
[batch-job-batchprocessBatch1-work-manager.03] com.mulesoft.module.batch.engine.threading.BatchRecordWork: Exception found while processing block 'be158611-147c-11e5-9d15-0026b9eef95d' for instance 'a4815df0-147c-11e5-85c6-0026b9eef95d' of batch job 'batchprocessBatch1'. Records will be queued back
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: sun/nio/cs/UTF_8
    at sun.nio.cs.UTF_8ConstructorAccess.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo$1.newInstance(Kryo.java:1062)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.newInstance(Kryo.java:1112)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.create(FieldSerializer.java:526)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:502)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:694)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:106)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:507)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:694)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:106)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:507)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:694)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:106)
```

Mule flows:

```
 <flow name="batchprocessFlow1" doc:name="batchprocessFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="${hostname}" port="${port}" path="psi2sfdc" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <batch:execute name="batchprocessBatch1" doc:name="Batch Execute"/>
    </flow>
    <batch:job name="batchprocessBatch1">
        <batch:input>
            <db:select config-ref="PostgreSQL" doc:name="Database">
                <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[SELECT * FROM clients_int WHERE int_status = 'Study']]></db:parameterized-query>
            </db:select>
        </batch:input>
        <batch:process-records>
            <batch:step name="getCont"> 
                <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="#[message.payload]"/>
            </batch:step>
            <batch:step name="Batch_Step">
                <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="#[message.payload]"/>                
                <batch:commit doc:name="Batch Commit" size="100">
                    <logger message="=========Inside Commit==========" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
                </batch:commit>
            </batch:step>
            <batch:step name="Enrich" >
                <logger level="INFO" message="=======Enrich=====" doc:name="Logger"/>
            </batch:step>
        </batch:process-records>
        <batch:on-complete>
            <logger message="Batch Job completed========#[message.payload]====" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </batch:on-complete>
    </batch:job>
```

Error-2

```
 org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentStartException: IOException: Negative seek offset
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.start(DefaultMuleApplication.java:143)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$4.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:98)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:129)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.start(ArtifactWrapper.java:93)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:26)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.guardedDeploy(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:310)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:330)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployExplodedApp(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:297)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployExplodedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:108)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployExplodedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:290)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:151)
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:130)
Caused by: org.mule.api.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Failed to invoke lifecycle phase "start" on object: org.mule.util.queue.DelegateQueueManager@1aa128c0
    at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase.applyLifecycle(DefaultLifecyclePhase.java:248)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager$RegistryLifecycleCallback.onTransition(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:273)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.invokePhase(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:152)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:123)
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistryBroker.fireLifecycle(AbstractRegistryBroker.java:76)
    at org.mule.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.fireLifecycle(MuleRegistryHelper.java:136)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:91)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:87)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.invokePhase(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:69)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:61)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.start(DefaultMuleContext.java:278)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.start(DefaultMuleApplication.java:123)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.mule.api.MuleRuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Negative seek offset
    at org.mule.util.queue.RandomAccessFileQueueStore.initialise(RandomAccessFileQueueStore.java:343)
    at org.mule.util.queue.RandomAccessFileQueueStore.<init>(RandomAccessFileQueueStore.java:45)
    at org.mule.util.queue.DualRandomAccessFileQueueStoreDelegate.<init>(DualRandomAccessFileQueueStoreDelegate.java:60)
    at org.mule.util.queue.DefaultQueueStore.setConfigAndDelegate(DefaultQueueStore.java:51)
    at org.mule.util.queue.DefaultQueueStore.<init>(DefaultQueueStore.java:30)
    at org.mule.util.queue.TransactionalQueueManager.createQueueStore(TransactionalQueueManager.java:55)
    at org.mule.util.queue.TransactionalQueueManager.getRecoveryQueue(TransactionalQueueManager.java:84)
    at org.mule.util.journal.queue.LocalTxQueueTransactionRecoverer.recover(LocalTxQueueTransactionRecoverer.java:84)
    at org.mule.util.queue.TransactionalQueueManager.start(TransactionalQueueManager.java:93)
    at org.mule.util.queue.DelegateQueueManager.start(DelegateQueueManager.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase.applyLifecycle(DefaultLifecyclePhase.java:237)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Negative seek offset
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.seek(Native Method)
    at org.mule.util.queue.RandomAccessFileQueueStore.moveFilePointerToNextData(RandomAccessFileQueueStore.java:369)
    at org.mule.util.queue.RandomAccessFileQueueStore.initi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is known issue in Mule3.5.1 but it has been fixed in Mule3.5.3. So upgrade to this version or don't use batch process in Mule with older version.

https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Mule+ESB+3.5.3+Release+Notes.

And for IllegalAccessError: sun/nio/cs/UTF_8 error:

Batch job uses persistent store. So, if the batch job name is the same, when application starts, it will load the failed jobs. To remove those, please try the following:

1) right click on the project -> Run As -> Run Configurations... 
2) in 'General' tab, scroll down to 'Clear Application Data', choose 'Always'

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure of the exact cause of this, but i get this running the batch module in Studio from time to time. It can be rectified by removing the queuestore data. If you are running from studio, navigate to the workspace you are using an remove the .mule folder or the specific project data in the .mule folder

Comment: it solved error-2 given above, now first error is coming i.e  java.lang.IllegalAccessError: sun/nio/cs/UTF_8